# birational classification of rationally connected 3-folds

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, birational-geometry

What is the birational classification of (smooth projective) **rationally connected 3-folds** (over algebraically closed fields of characteristic $0$ or even $\mathbf{C}$, if $\mathrm{char}(k) = p > 0$, one should perhaps better ask for *separably* rationally connected 3-folds).

There is perhaps an article of Iskovskikh, but I do not have access to MathSciNet at the moment.

Comment: This is completely unknown, and probably hopeless. Just one example : taking the desingularization of a quartic threefold with 1,2, ...,45 nodes gives RC threefolds, most of which are very likely of different birational type.

Comment: As a comment, this (birational) class is strictly larger than the class of Fano type varieties for dimension greater or equal than 6. http://arxiv.org/abs/1406.3752